# Cramer-Rao bound (CRB) and Root-Mean-Square-Error / Mean-Square-Error (RMSE / MSE)

Tags: estimation, monte-carlo, estimators, rms, cramer-rao

My question is regarding the comparison between the CRB of a given vector parameter and RMSE/MSE obtained from Monte-Carlo (MC) simulation. The approach I used is this:

For $\boldsymbol{\theta} \in \mathbb{R}^D$, the RMSE of the estimate is
$$\text{RMSE} = \dfrac{1}{D} \: \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{N}\sum \lvert \lvert \widehat{\boldsymbol{\theta}} - \boldsymbol{\theta} \rvert \rvert_2^2}$$
where $N$ is the number of MC runs.

To get RMSE from the CRB, I do the following
$$\text{RMSE} = \dfrac{1}{D} \: \sqrt{\text{Trace} \left( \mathbf{I}^{-1}(\boldsymbol{\theta}) \right)}$$
where $\mathbf{I}(\boldsymbol{\widehat{\theta}})$ is the Fisher information matrix.

The above formulations are based on the desire to have a scalar measure of CRB for vector parameters. With this in mind, my questions are:

1. When the estimator is unbiased and $\mathbf{I}(\boldsymbol{\widehat{\theta}})$ is diagonal, then this formulation is exact. Is this statement correct? Is there a proof somewhere?
2. Is this still suitable when $\mathbf{I}(\boldsymbol{\widehat{\theta}})$ is not diagonal and the off-diagonal elements are significant? My experience says **No!**. Then what would be the appropriate comparison?
3. Extending the question above, what is the appropriate metric to use for a biased estimator with non-diagonal $\mathbf{I}(\boldsymbol{\widehat{\theta}})$?

I will appreciate appropriate references for the answers to the question.